# Stars Around _Nullable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to understand the placement of the stars in the error argument of this function:

`+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj 
                       options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt 
                         error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;`

I do know that if the stars are next to each other, this would mean we are referencing the address of the parameter. I believe that was how it was done in this function prior to nullability being introduced (i.e. `error:(NSError **)error;`

So why does _Nullable sit between the two stars and not something like `error:(NSError ** _Nullable)error;` to express this?

Comment: `NSError * _Nullable *` means the exact same thing as `NSError **`, except that it's making it clear that you can pass it `nil` if you don't want `dataWithJSONObject` to pass back a reference to an error object, even if there really was an error. E.g. you can call it as `NSData *data = [JSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:nil];`, and you won't capture the `NSError` associated with the error, if there was any.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, the attribute modifies the type to its left.

- `NSError* _Nullable error` is an object reference that can be set to `nil`.
- `NSError* _Nonnull error` is an object reference that must not be `nil`.
- `NSError* _Nullable * _Nullable outError` is a pointer, that can be `NULL`, that points to an object reference that can be `nil`.
- `NSError* _Nullable * _Nonnull outError` is a pointer, that *must not* be `NULL`, that points to an object reference that can be `nil`.
- `NSError* _Nonnull * _Nonnull outError` is a pointer, that *must not* be `NULL`, that points to an object reference that *must not* be `nil`.